# Gazebo for Noetic not working in WSL

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did a clean install of Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 2.  This installs Gazebo 11, but Gazebo does not run when I type:

```
gazebo
```

Other X11 utilities like xeyes work fine in WSL, so the X-Server and DISPLAY are fine.  I also went to the official Gazebo page: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install, and followed those directions, which just confirmed that I already have the latest version of Gazebo.

Has anyone gotten Gazebo working with Noetic in WSL2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367135/gazebo-for-noetic-not-working-in-wsl/) by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-07**:\

> Has anyone gotten Gazebo working with Noetic?

Shouldn't the question be: "has anyone gotten Gazebo (in Noetic) working *on WSL2*"?

If Gazebo didn't work in Noetic, I assume ROS Answers would be full of posts about it not working.

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2020-12-07**:
I would have thought so.  But I would also expect that after uninstalling Noetic and Gazebo, and doing a clean install it would just work, but it doesn't.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-07**:\

> But I would also expect that after uninstalling Noetic and Gazebo, and doing a clean install it would just work, but it doesn't.

I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Gazebo is a rather heavy 3D application making use of OpenGL. Regular X applications are not. Comparing `xeyes` to Gazebo isn't really useful, as the former doesn't come close to the complexity in the graphics pipeline of the latter.

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2020-12-07**:
Ah, I figured it out.  I had forgotten to set: export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0
When I ran in Melodic, it gave me an error if I forgot this, but Noetic doesn't give an error, it just doesn't run.  It was helpful discussing this with you, @gvdhoom, thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-08**:
Please post your edit as an answer instead.

Then accept your own answer.

**Comment by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) on 2020-12-08**:
Okay, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem and solution.  Make sure to set this environment variable before running gazebo:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0
```

---

Originally posted by [Morris](https://answers.ros.org/users/24538/morris/) with karma: 35 on 2020-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0